# inner join Query not working

Tags: mysql, database, inner-join

```
select distinct Analysed.resultId,bugOwner,Analysed.bugId as BugDet,bugType,testCaseName from Bug INNER JOIN Analysed on Analysed.bugId=Bug.bugId INNER JOIN Results on Analysed.runId=Results.runId where Analysed.runId=64
```

The above works fine.

Now I have another table Results (resultId,runId,analysed,testname)

I also want to include testname in my other query so I added,

```
select Analysed.resultId,bugOwner,Analysed.bugId as BugDet,bugType,testCaseName from Bug 
INNER JOIN 
Analysed on Analysed.bugId=Bug.bugId 
INNER JOIN Results on Analysed.runId=Results.runId
where Analysed.runId=64
```

But this query is incorrect. It duplicates the records.I guess its taking some cross product or something.
Does anyone know how to solve it ?

Data:

[image: Results]
[image: Analysed]

Comment: Sample data with the expected output. Or you can always apply the `DISTINCT`

Comment: can u show me how to use distinct in above query ?

Comment: there is no column named runId  in your Result table, it shouldbe Results.resultid

Comment: I am not sure if it will give you the correct result or not but you can use it like `SELECT Distinct column1,....from ....`

Comment: @Arun : Sorry,edited now

Comment: incorrect query means ? any error ? or wrong result ???

Comment: @Arun : It duplicates the records meaning one record is shown 100 times

Comment: @Arun : Edited again.

Comment: @Coder of Code-distinct doesn't work

Comment: Add some sample data with expected output. So can give you exact query.

Comment: provide your tabale data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the data. It clearly got multiple `Results` for each `Analysed` (or even multiple `Analysed` for each `Bug`)

You can use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` to get rid of the duplicates or, depending on your requirements/schema/data filter for a column like that `analysed` flag to get just one `Analysed` record per `Results` row.

```
select DISTINCT Analysed.resultId,bugOwner,Analysed.bugId as BugDet,bugType,testCaseName from Bug 
INNER JOIN 
Analysed on Analysed.bugId=Bug.bugId 
INNER JOIN Results on Analysed.runId=Results.runId
where Analysed.runId=64
```

Comment: I suggest you to learn the basics on aggregation, you ill not get far in SQL without it